# Extract common terms between each pair of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have this dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['This here is text','My Text was here','This was not ready']), columns=['Text'])

                 Text
0    This here is text
1    My Text was here
2    This was not ready
3    nothing common
```

I want to create a new dataframe with the following results:

```
row1 row2    common_text
  0    1        here,text
  0    2        this
  1    2        was
```

A new dataframe with all common words between each pair of rows. Also, if two rows have nothing in common, then ignore that pair like in case of 1,3 and 0,3.

My question is, is there any faster or Pythonic way to do it instead of iterating over all rows twice to extract the common terms and storing them together ?

Comment: You can try the bag of words approch to strore all common words in a list and then use this list to check in which row you find a word out of this list. [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html) you can find the documentation for feature extraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations

result = []

# Iterate through each pair of rows.
for row_1, row_2 in combinations(df['Text'].index, 2):
    # Find set of lower case words stripped of whitespace for each row in pair.
    s1, s2  = [set(df.loc[row, 'Text'].lower().strip().split()) for row in (row_1, row_2)]
    # Find the common words to the pair of rows.
    common = s1.intersection(s2)
    if common:
        # If there are words in common, append to the results as a common separated string (could also append the set of list of words).
        result.append([row_1, row_2, ",".join(common)])

>>> pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['row1', 'row2', 'common_text'])
   row1  row2 common_text
0     0     1   text,here
1     0     2        this
2     1     2         was
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one loop, go for `itertools.product` but it’s probably less pythonic.

```
import itertools

# new_data_frame = ...
for row1, row2 in itertools.product(range(len(df)), range(len(df)):
    # possibly add
```

For getting common words, you can do

```
set(text1.lower().split()) & set(text2.lower().split())
```

which is pretty pythonic. For performance reasons, I would save each sentence as a set in an intermediate array, and then union these sets later.

```
temp = [set(s.lower().split()) for s in df['Text']]
```

Comment: You probably want to throw in something about `str.casefold` when making the set according to OP's example.